# Deserialize array values to form using jquery.deserialize

Tags: arrays, json, forms, serialization

My C# web method uses JavaScriptSerializer to return a JSON object in string format called jSONstring. My javascript then uses [jquery.deserialize](https://github.com/kflorence/jquery-deserialize) and does the following:

```
$("#form").deserialize(JSON.parse(jSONstring));
```

This seems to work fine except when mapping to an array of elements.

My HTML is as follows:

```
<input name="AccountID" value="" />
<input name="Account[0].name" value="" />
<input name="Account[1].name" value="" />
<input name="Account[2].name" value="" />
```

The JSON object returned from the server looks like:

```
'{"AccountID": 123, "Account":[{"name": "AccountName1"},{"name": "AccountName2"},{"name": "AccountName3"}]}'
```

After calling deserialize the AccountID is updated but the account names are never updated to AccountName1, AccountName2, AccountName3.

I tried renaming my input elements to the following and it still doesn't work:

```
<input name="Account.name" value="" />
<input name="Account.name" value="" />
<input name="Account.name" value="" />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That format is not supported by the plugin, it only supports data generated from [jQuery.serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize), [jQuery.serializeArray](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray) and [jQuery.serializeObject](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-misc-plugins/#serializeobject) (unofficial). That said, it would not be hard to write a small function that would convert the returned JSON object you have into one of the formats listed above. Another option would be using a different method of serialization, such as parametizing it.